# Как поставить свою иконку на push уведомления firebase, когда приложение в фоне или закрыто?

Tags: android, уведомления, firebase, android-notification, push-уведомления

Андроид изыучаю не так давно, сейчас появилась необходимость сделать push уведомления. Поставил firebase, прописал метод onMessageReceived, но, насколько понял, в фоне он не работает. Как сделать так, чтобы когда приложение в бэкграунде, отображало push с кастомной иконкой?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, в метод `onMessageReceived` приходят сообщения только когда приложение активно. Когда приложение в фоне - сообщения сразу попадает в нотификации. Вы можете установить свойство `click_action` на  это сообщение а у себя в приложении ловить его через `intent-filter`.

Пример

тело сообщения которое отправляет сервер:

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'data',
    priority: 'high',
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: false,
    timeToLive: 10000,

    data: {
        message: 'Message from gcm server',
        action: 'some action'
    },

    notification: {
        tag : 'hasData',
        title: "English for Founders",
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        color: "#22C064",
        sound: "notification_sound",
        body: "This is a GCM notification that will be displayed ASAP.",
        click_action: "OPEN_APP" // make intent-filter in Manifest.xml for this action
    }
});
```

У вас в `Manifest.xml` прописан фильтр на `action` - `OPEN_APP` на определенное активити.

В итоге телефон получит `push-уведомление` из которого вы сможете получить `click_action` и когда `Activity` запуститься, в методе `onCreate` вы с можете получить еще и `data` с этого сообщения, вот так:

```
public static void parseExtras (Bundle intentExtras){
    if (intentExtras != null) {
        for (String key : intentExtras.keySet()) {
            try {
                String value = intentExtras.getString(key);
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            }catch (ClassCastException e){ Log.wtf(TAG, "Cannot parse extras, ClassCastException");}
        }
    }
}
```

А картинку если вам надо отображать, пропишите ее название в теге `icon`

Comment: Спасибо! А подскажите ещё, возможно ли так, чтобы приложение обрабатывало сообщение? То есть чтобы даже в бэкграунде срабатывал onMessageReceived? Например, чтобы в некотором  городе уведомление приходило, а в другом нет?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю , это - не возможно

Comment: Если послать сообщение без секции notification, а только с секцией data внутри, то оно дойдет и обработается в любом случае. только вот код в onMessageReceived() должен быть очень короткий иначе он завершается раньше чем отработает. Второй вариант запустить службу и обрабатывать в ней.